# Can I have bodyshop made the frame symmetrical without putting parts on?

Tags: body, frame

I have a small crash and front bumper, hood was damage. The frame inside is also bent. My budget is tight so I can't fix everything at once. Is it possible to ask body shop pull out the frame to its previous position and I'll find parts to install later by myself?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes - but you have to find one prepared to do only that work. Setting a car on a jig to straighten the frame is a long labour intensive process and takes skill and knowledge. The costs are usually "shared" with the rest of the work body, paint etc